# Average sales per weekday with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, weekday

I have some transaction data for two years that I want to analyse in R. It has the following structure:

```
date                   weekday  salesval
1 2003-10-31           Mi        425.36
2 2003-10-31           Mi       1504.50
3 2003-10-31           Mi        170.14
4 2002-03-12           Mo       -215.80
5 2002-02-08           Mi          0.00
6 2002-04-17           Do        215.80
```

I want to illustrate the average amount of total sales per weekday by using the ggplot2 graphic system.

I have tried this by using the `stat_summary` function but as you can see, my approach only calculates the average sales value per transaction per weekday. But I want the average total sales per weekday.

```
ggplot(data, aes(weekday, salesval)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y = function(x) { sum(x) / length(x) }, geom = "bar") +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = dollar) +
    ylab("Sales") +
    xlab("Weekday") +
    ggtitle("Average Sales per Weekday")
```

[image]

I know what is wrong with my code, but I have no idea how to achieve my actual goal.

Hope somebody can help me.

Best wishes,
Marcus

Comment: A more flexible approach is to do your data aggregation first using a library dedicated to that purpose, like `dplyr` (`group_by()` and `summarize()`), and then to use `ggplot2` for visualizing the aggregated data frame.

Comment: @mpjdem yes, you are probably right. But is there also a way to do it one-step wise with ggplot2?

Comment: I'm not a big `ggplot2` expert but you have to do a double aggregation here, first on date then on weekday. Summary functions only take single vectors, so any solution using `stat_summary` only would be awkward at best I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

You could provide an aggregating function as the data

```
ggplot(data = aggregate(df$salesval, list(df$weekday), mean), aes(Group.1, x)) +
     geom_col()
```

Based on the sample data, that would create this

[image]

Comment: But this is not exactly what I want. I need to do a double aggregation so that the averaged total sales volume per weekday is reflected. Your numbers reflect the average sales volume per transaction per weekday. And I am especially interested in the question if there is way to to it one-step wise with ggplot.

Comment: Ahh, ok sorry. The answer is the same though. You could just provide the doubley aggregated data straight into `ggplot(data = ` argument. Though things will be getting a bit messy. My own preference would be to pass the data in as I wanted it, just because I would find it easier to read the process as: manipulate > plot

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(weekday) %>% summarise(salesval=mean(salesval)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(weekday, salesval)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to build your dataset first and then plot:

```r
library(dplyr)
data1 <- data %>% 
  group_by(weekday) %>%
  summarise(salesval = mean(salesval)) 

a <- ggplot(data1, aes(weekday, salesval)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity')

a
```